# Is there any plugin for Intellij IDEA for running Clojure tests?

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, ide

I have been programming in Clojure for some time now on Intellij IDEA. I love the language and IDEA is, by far, my favorite IDE. But one thing that annoys me is not being able to run tests from the IDE and see the red/green/orange bar. Is there any plugin for that? Or, at least, some clever trick?

Answer (score 1):

Searching gives two main variants:
Leiningen (as in [this](http://www.seekingclojure.com/post/21546596502/intellij-clj-plugins) tutorial) and lazytest. 
There is inconvenience that lazytest still hasn't integration with IDEA as plugin.